# How to learn how to play Shadowrun 5e?

Tags: new-players, shadowrun-sr5

I have recently bought the Shadowrun 5e Core Rulebook, because I like the setting and would like to start a campaign with a few friends — each of who have experience with Tabletop RPGs in general, but not Shadowrun.

My problem is that I am absolutely overwhelmed with the system and just the sheer amount of information there is.

My question essentially is: Do I have a chance of learning Shadowrun on my own (or rather, in a group of noobs) — and if so, how? – or do I have to play with veterans before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

Though shadowrun is surely a *complex* game system. It is by no means impossible to learn by yourself. The game is designed to cover three different aspects of the setting:

- **Mundane**: These are the rules for mundane people, those who can neither cast spells, nor are willing to bend the matrix to their will. This covers a lot of the game rules actually, from combat to contacts and finding a job in the shadows.
- **The Astral**: These are the rules for the *mystical* aspect of the setting, the *other world*, magic spells, spirits, rituals and characters who can channel their *chi* into their fists.
- **The Matrix**: Here we have all the technological stuff happening, from security cameras, to the cybereye of the guards blocking your path. These rules are the realm of *deckers* and *technomancers*, and those characters should know those rules more than any of the other two.

This is also how the world is divided in the setting, we basically have three different worlds with different rules about how to interact with them. But each of these worlds are an important part of the setting on their own, with a lot of lore and mechanics involved.

The GM is expected to know all of this. But he doesn't necessarily have to memorize those rules. Whenever you decide to GM your first shadowrun adventure, try starting with one of the beginner adventures (or [Missions](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/products-page/missions/srm-04-00-back-in-business/)). These are well-written adventures that will guide you through a normal shadowrun, convering all aspects of a regular adventure: finding the job, doing legwork, running the shadows, figuring out the plot twist, and finally, *getting paid for it*.

If you haven't already, take a look on the [Quickstart Rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/E-CAT27QSR_SR5-Quick-Start-Rules.pdf), these are ideal for convention play, as they are simplified rules and provide an example of play with a short adventure scenario so GM and players can get a feel of the system. The [Splintered State](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/119804/Shadowrun-Splintered-State?src=also_purchased) is an **introdutory adventure** for 5th that deals mostly with corporations and the intrigue between them. While the [Sprawl Wilds](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/116158/Shadowrun-Sprawl-Wilds) is a collection of convention adventures designed for short sessions (4 to 6 hours).

You can also **delegate jobs** to your players so they can help you out. If a player wants to be a hacker, ask him to make notes of the rules that are relevant to hacking things, infiltrate nodes, cybercombat and erasing his tracks. If one of the players is a mage, ask him to make notes of the summoning rules, how spirit services work, what each of his spells do and how to resist them, etc.

Of course, being such a rich setting, the more you read, the more you will know. So don't feel discouraged by the overwhelmingness of the game system, you don't have to use all the rules at once.

### Personal experience

My personal experience with the setting is this: We played a couple of shadowrun games back in 2nd, but without any magic or mystical races, only humans. We had a hacker and other mundane characters and they ran through a few jobs i gave them.

Few years later, with a different group of people, i decided i wanted to play the 4th edition (the book *is* gorgeous), i read *most* of the *core rulebook*, asked my players to make some characters, we sat down and played the introductory adventure found on the [Runner's Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936876922). It was a *blast* and an immediate success. Then we kept playing more and more, i kept reading the core book and bought the other hardcovers, and eventually we were all familiar with the rules.

5th edition came in, we migrated without issues and still play it now and then.

Comment: Alright. This might limit our first sessions a bit, but then again, I started Pathfinder as a Ranger and not a Psychic-Antipaladin multiclass whatever.

Comment: The same holds for other RPGs... play a class that is mundane before you try playing a more complex class.

Answer (score 2):

I want to second the posts on living campaign/organized play because that is how I got into it myself.

The Organized Play for Shadowrun is "[Shadowrun Missions](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/missions/)" I am still mostly noob-ish but have a lot of laughs every time I sit and play. Most SRM GMs are very good at helping new players. "Missions" is not the most in-depth character-discovering campaign, but it is a good way to meet local people. They have a facebook group (can't access that here from work)

As a side-note, Shadowrun Online, while fun, is not the place to learn how to play the tabletop version. Get a feel for the setting perhaps, but not the rules.

If SRM is not for you, here are some nuggets of wisdom I gleaned over the years, from my own first GM.

**Start simple:** a group of people with limited magic and cybernetics, to get used to the world before you move on to the main stage. This will allow everyone to digest how magic, cybernetics, decking, and all that good stuff works. Avoid the pit trap of being drawn to all the shiny bells and whistles. My first GM told us not to have any decker or riggers, he provided a NPC to fulfill these roles if/when we needed them.

**Do a few trial runs:** Before you start into a massive campaign, run a few short missions where the players and you discover the odd elements one at a time.

**Use the Templates:** Have them all be from the same 'hood or gang for a few trial runs. Then when everyone is excited, familiar and happy, allow them to transfer their Karma/NuY to their permanent character. One big benefit of this? They created a bunch of NPCs you can use in future runs...

**You're gonna fail:** There, I said it. That's fine. Don't panic. It will happen, but learn the lessons and move on.

**Keep it simple:** Once more, for emphasis.

Comment: Yes, I have run some Pathfinder games before and the basic idea of "Keep it simple" seems to be universal

Answer (score 1):

Our gaming group has had much the same issues that you describe when we started with Shadowrun 5e a couple of years ago. The main theme here is basically to take it step-by-step, learning some elements first in order to not get overwhelmed by all the rules.

Here is what we did to make our lives easier:

We ditched the entire **astral/magic system** and the **non-human races** for our first campaign.

- This was in parts due to us agreeing that, for us, these don't necessarily belong into a cyberpunk universe (YMMV)...
- ... and in parts because this *takes away a lot of complexity*.
- The changes needed here aren't very big and mostly concern character creation (if you're interested in our house rules I could dig them up for you).

We (sort of) ignored the **matrix** for the first 2-3 adventures.

- Yes, this takes away a *big* part of the game - but we felt that it wouldn't hurt our game to only include this later on after we got acquainted with the basic rules and the mundane part of the setting.
- For example you could play a first short adventure/campaign without any deckers in your group - and basically hand-wave any NPC decking.

Getting into the **vibes**.

- This depends on how familiar you and your group are with cyberpunk settings - for us it was the first such game, thus we were all eager and curious to getting to know this new world.
- What we did was to basically consume as many (re)sources of information and inspiration beforehand as possible. This included books (William Gibsons *Neuromancer* is an obvious example here), graphic novels (e.g. *Akira*) and movies (*Bladerunner*, *Ghost in the Shell*). We also made it a point that we tried to find pictures online for many things that came up in our campaign (PCs, NPCs, sceneries, buildings, equipment, corporate logos, ...).
- This allowed us to getting a good *feel* for how this strange new world was behaving and getting really immersed - all-the-while enabling us thus to focus more on the complicated rules during our sessions.

Comment: By non-human, you mean you ditched all meta-humans? That's very limiting..

Comment: I think this is more about customizing the game rather than learning it.  ditching the matrix and all metas, and the magic system?  I don't know if I'd still call it shadowrun.

Comment: I wouldn't call that playing Shadowrun either, so -1 from me.

Comment: @T.J.L.: My intent was not to suggest stripping Shadowrun of all of its distinguishing features... The point I was trying to make was to introduce these features _one after the other_, as each of them on its own can easily be as complex as other rule systems in their entirety. I reworded some things to try and point that out.

Comment: Your first bullet point says otherwise. Magic and metahumanity are part of the fabric of Shadowrun - they drive a great deal of the setting background. If you don't think they belong in a cyberpunk universe, that's fine. However, it means you're not playing Shadowrun - you're playing "a cyberpunk game using Shadowrun's rules".

Comment: @T.J.L. You can limit the complexity of the game by preventing players from choosing metahuman and magic options while still having those things in the setting.  It doesn't make it any less Shadowrun.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Sure... but that is very much *not* what the first bullet point says. The author is welcome to edit if he wishes, but as currently written, my point is valid and accurate.

Comment: @T.J.L., look, I gave a set of suggestions from personal experience that greatly helped our group of players with exactly the problem that OP was describing, namely getting into the complex setting and rules of Shadowrun. I don't want to get into an argument here about what what your ideas of Shadowrun are or how *you* would solve the problem - you are welcome to write an answer yourself where you can formulate these points.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest playing with veterans first if at all possible.
There is an organized play group for Shadowrun out there at: [Living Campaigns](http://forums.shadowruntabletop.com/index.php?board=19.0)

I think this the fastest way to learn as well as get an idea for how to GM.